# Classes acculumating when cloning a template for a data array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've ran into a problem when cloning a template div to create elements for a dataset.

The problem is that classes accumulate between creating the elements for each data record.

Example JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
     {cls: 'test1',text:'test1'},
     {cls: 'test2',text:'test2'},
     {cls: 'test3',text:'test3'}
  ];
  for(var x in data)
  {
     var item = $('#itemTemplate').clone().removeClass('template');
     item.addClass(data[x].cls).html(data[x].text);
     $('#test-container').prepend(item);
  }
});
```

And the HTML body:

```
<div id="test-container">
</div>
<div id="itemTemplate" class="template">
</div>
```

This produces:

```
<div id="test-container">
   <div id="itemTemplate" class="test1 test2 test3">test3</div>
   <div id="itemTemplate" class="test1 test2">test2</div>
   <div id="itemTemplate" class="test1">test1</div>
</div>
```

Notice the `test1 test2 test3` where it should just be `test3`. Am I missing something or just got it plain wrong?

Tested in jQuery 1.7 & 1.6.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should also remove the id from the cloned elements. else it doesn't know which one he needs to clone

```
item.addClass(data[x].cls).html(data[x].text).removeAttr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the following line will remove all classes on the element, allowing you to add just the one you want.

`var item = $('#itemTemplate').clone().removeClass()`

The underlying problem is due to the fact that you're cloning the element whilst maintaining the ID. The next time you use the ID selector you're picking up multiple elements. Therefore t would also be worth changing the ID of the cloned element before appending it:

`var item = $('#itemTemplate').clone().attr("id", data[x].text).removeClass()`